# Rest API protection for public URls

Tags: rest, security, ionic-framework, rest-security

i am building a Hybrid mobile app using IONIC 3. The App  has a set of pages  accessible by authenticated users and a set  for anonymous users. The public pages are for registration requests etc..

The app uses rest services  with JWT authentication for all the private pages. 
What kind of security approach should i follow  to ensure that the public rest services are not abused.

For Example on the web we either have CSRF tokens or CAPTCHA for Public Web pages how can i protect a public REST services.